# How to remove slashes from array key using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting some slashes inside my JSON array key using PHP. I am providing my code below.

```
$result[] = $fcm->send_fcm_notify($device_id, $message);
echo  json_encode($result);
```

The output of the above code is below:

```
{\"multicast_id\":7339396188598826217,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1482327583160431%2d865361f9fd7ecd\"}]}"]
```

I need to remove the slashes, because I need to check `success==1`.

Comment: That JSON string is _not_ the result of the given code. It actually is invalid.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php with this function you are able to remove the escape characters, but json_encode won't generate those so are you escaping anything?

Comment: Looks like that method already returns a JSON encoded string. So why do you encode it a second time?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) first on response then do [`json_decode()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiq4Inht4XRAhUcOVAKHSquDecQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.json-decode.php&usg=AFQjCNEfzaIfzofmQZOFSYuv9P5S_iMCJA)

Try

```
$json = json_decode(stripslashes('{\"multicast_id\":7339396188598826217,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1482327583160431%2d865361f9fd7ecd\"}]}'));

if( $json->success == '1' )
{
    echo "I got it";
}
```

[Output](https://eval.in/702141)

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode() to conrect received json string into multidimensional array then you can use json_encode() to print that array in json format without any slashes.

But make sure your received json string is valid as i can see the json code is not valid this will throw error when you use json_decode.

Your json string is wrong so json_encode will not work i have removed extra **]** at the end of string so that json can parse without any error.

```
<?php 
     $json_code = "{\"multicast_id\":7339396188598826217,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1482327583160431%2d865361f9fd7ecd\"}]}";

     $result =  json_decode($json_code,true);


   //for json output use json_encode()

    echo json_encode($code);
?>
```